# Calculate algorithm's complexity containing predefined methods

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity-theory

Having this simple Java code :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Simple {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(5);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(3);
        Collections.sort(list);
    }
}
```

1. How can i calculate this algorithm's complexity without knowing the complexity of Collection.sort method ?
2. Am i supposed to go to the java doc and search for Collection.sort source code and then calculate its complexity ?

NOTE : Collection.sort is just an example of predefined methods .

Thanks

Comment: It is absurd to look for the complexity of a print function.

Comment: I think it is safe to assume the complexity would be linear relative to the length of the String you are printing.

Comment: +Sanjeev Sharma . Then how to calculate this algorithm's complexity ? Isn't an algorithm ?

Comment: You just posted another question with of a similar nature. Why are you not satisfied with the other answers in that question? You should read some literature about what *is* an algorithm and what isn't. This hello-world program has a constant time complexity for example, since there is no input. Please stop spamming and actually read the answers and comments of your questions.

Comment: @MCHAppy You are not actually doing any *computation* in printing a string. That's why.

Comment: @JohanS  . I am free to ask questions . am i asking stupid questions ? if yes then give me the exact complexity ?

Comment: @MCHAppy actually you are not free to ask any kind of questions, you are free to ask questions which, for example, aren't exactly duplicates of your previous questions, just because you didn't get any good answers on those. And by the way, if you read my comment you would have seen the time complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can i calculate this algorithm's complexity without knowing the complexity of System.out.println method ?

Strictly speaking, you can't.

On the other hand, it is not normal practice to include the detailed complexity of I/O in algorithmic analysis.  Normally we assume that I/O behaves in the way that it is generally understood to behave ... because a real complexity analysis would be intractable.

In practice it is *assumed* that simple I/O (like this) has complexity of `O(N)` where `N` is the number of bytes / characters that are read or written.

> Am i supposed to go to the java doc and search for System.out.println source code and then calculate its complexity ?

No.  See above.

---

> Ok understood , but what if i call the sort predefined java method ?

The javadoc for `Collections.sort(List<?>)` says:

> This implementation defers to the List.sort(Comparator) method using the specified list and a null comparator.

which in turn says:

> Implementation note: This implementation is a stable, adaptive, iterative mergesort that requires far fewer than n lg(n) comparisons when the input array is partially sorted, while offering the performance of a traditional mergesort when the input array is randomly ordered. If the input array is nearly sorted, the implementation requires approximately n comparisons. Temporary storage requirements vary from a small constant for nearly sorted input arrays to n/2 object references for randomly ordered input arrays.

---

In general, to determine the complexity of classes in the standard class libraries, read the javadoc, and if the javadoc doesn't say then either locate and analyse the source code ... or make reasonable assumptions based on your knowledge of data structures actually used.

The circumstances should determine whether or not your complexity analysis needs to be *rigorous*.  If rigour is not required you can take short-cuts in your analysis ... provided you get the right answer :-)

In either case, be aware that algorithms are nearly always "an implementation detail" and that performance and space complexity is (at least in theory) subject to change.

Comment: Ok understood , but what if i call the sort predefined java method ? See EDIT

Comment: I think that the javadoc mentions the complexity of the the built-in `sort` algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

This hello-world program has a constant time complexity for example, since there is no input.
And You are not actually doing any computation in printing a string.

Answer (score 0):

The sample doesn't have any input, so O is a constant, or O(1). Complexity is only interesting when you have an input of size N for instance, and some sort of loop in your program or a recursive call to the function in question, so the running time depends on the input. Like Sanjeev Sharma noted, in this case looking for complexity is absurd.

Comment: +AndroidCoder85  See EDIT